# Installed XCode, but GCC doesn't work

Tags: c, xcode, macos, gcc

I recently installed OSX Mavericks along with XCode 5.1.1. I also installed command line tools because I need to use GCC to compile some of my programs (since they won't compile correctly with clang). When I went to the command line, I typed in 'gcc' and was greeted with this message:

```
            clang: error: no input files
```

I have tried several installs of command line tools and even a reinstall of Xcode itself, but the 'gcc' command still points to clang. Is there any way that I can get gcc installed on OSX Mavericks?

**EDIT:** I have tried to install gcc from source and I have also used a package manager (homebrew) to attempt to install it, but these two methods have not worked.

Comment: ?? `gcc file_to_compile.c -o executable_file`

Comment: Where did you install gcc?  It sounds like you didn't install it to /usr/bin/gcc, which is clang on mavericks.  And if /usr/bin comes first in the path, then typing gcc will run that one first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC hasn't shipped with Xcode for quite a while now.  Clang is, of course, a working C compiler, so you should be able to make use if it instead.

If you actually need GCC itself for some reason, you can easily compile it from source.  That process (especially in grabbing the dependencies) is made a bit more straightforward if you use a package manager like [homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I probably should have mentioned in my question that compiling GCC from source and using homebrew to install GCC doesn't work either. I will add an edit for that now

Comment: @user2344996 - Can you provide more information on that?  brew gcc should work nicely on Mavericks, provided you've got the command line tools fully installed